# Matching floating point range using regular expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression, that matches within a range of floats.

For the range 12.33 - 13.41 I tried the following regex:

(12.[3-9][3-9]|13.?[0-4][0-1]?)\d{0,2}

but it doesn't match i.e. 12.41 or 13.39.

Is this possible with regular expressions?

Kind regards,
bernie70

Comment: Post your attempts..

Comment: In what language are you trying to do this? Must be a much simpler solution for it?

Comment: Do you just want to match the decimal part, or the complete number?

Comment: I want to match the whole number.

Comment: I have already a solution in shell with an if construct, but I was experimenting with regexp and I want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it worth it, but it is possible.
Try with:

```
(12.(3[3-9]|[4-9]\d))|(13(.([0-3]\d|4[01]))?)
```

it means:

- `12.` -- starts with '12.',
- `3[3-9]` -- 3 followed by digit from range 3 to 9 (33-39),
- `|` -- OR
- `[4-9]\d` -- digit from range 4 to 9 followed by any digit (40-99),
- `|` -- OR
- `13` -- starts with '13'
- `.` -- dot
- `[0-3]\d` -- digit from range 0 to 3 followed by any digit,
- `|` -- OR
- `4[01]` -- 4 followed by 0 or 1,
- `?` -- zero or one time

and `(.([0-3]\d|4[01]))?` is treated as a one group, to allow '13', but not '13.'

It will match numbers like: 12.33, 12.99, 13.41 ,13 ,12.41 ,13.39 ,etc. 
and will ignore:  12.32, 13.42, etc.

Your code didn't work because:

```
(12.[3-9][3-9]|13.?[0-4][0-1]?)\d{0,2}
```

- `[3-9][3-9]` - allows only numbers from ranges (33-39,43-49,53-59,...),
- `[0-4][0-1]` - allows only numbers (00,01,10,11,20,21,30,31,40,41),

so there is huge omitted range

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the tip.

I modified the regex a little bit to the following:

(12.(3[3-9]|[4-9])).*|(13(.([0-3][0-8])).*)|^(13.[0-3][9][0]*)$

So I can match the range I want.

Answer (score -1):

A straight forward way to match the float range 12.33 - 13.41 is :

`12\.(?:3[3-9]|[4-9]\d)|13\.(?:[0-3]\d|4[01])`

Expanded

```
   #  12.33  to  12.99
   12 \. 
   (?:
        3 [3-9] 
     |  [4-9] \d 
   )
|  
   #  13.00  to  13.41
   13 \. 
   (?:
        [0-3] \d 
     |  4 [01] 
   )
```